# `open myfile.pdf` raises "no permission" error

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, pdf, preview

Specifically, opening a terminal and writing `open myfile.pdf` causes a Dialog box in Preview with

> The file “myfile.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it"
>
> To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

Note this also happens with `open -a Preview.app myfile.pdf` but does **not** happen for `open -a Skim.app myfile.pdf`. In addition, this problem only manifested after my MBP forcibly upgraded itself to Catalina 10.15.7 without my consent; everything was working normally before.

Now, the error is totally bogus because the file permissions are `-rw-r--r--`, the owner of the file is me (i.e., `$USER`) and the group is `staff`. What's more, this file resides in `$mydir` with hundreds of other PDF files. They all have the same file permissions, owner and group IDs. Most of them will open fine with a call to `open` from the Terminal, but some of them won't. Maddeningly, I cannot determine a straightforward way to isolate what is causing this OS bug.

I have followed other suggestions on this site, to no avail. In fact, I thought I fixed the issue ([see here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/75412/emacs-unable-to-open-pdf-files-in-preview-permission-denied?noredirect=1#comment123397_75412)), which involved deleting some Preview Container contents. However, that attempted solution only improved the problem, but did not fix it entirely.

If you have a new suggestion that's not already mentioned elsewhere on this site, I'd be grateful to read it.

**EDIT**

Following the request in the comments:

```
➜ ls -lOe@ myfile.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 $USER  staff  - 1081682  5 Apr  2022 myfile.pdf
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS        16
    com.apple.quarantine         22
    com.dropbox.attrs        26
```

Note that I can open the PDF in Preview without any errors if I double click it in Finder (and have Preview set as my default PDF viewer).

I did as requested and executed

```bash
cd my/PDFs/folder/
chmod 644 *.pdf
chown $USER:staff *.pdf
```

Miraculously, `myfile.pdf` is now open-able in Preview using `open -a Preview.app myfile.pdf`. Also miraculously, other PDF files in the same folder (let's call them `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf`) **remain unopen-able** using `open -a Preview.app ...` **but** they can still be opened in Preview by double clicking in Finder with Preview as default; or via `open -a Skim.app file1.pdf`.

**EDIT2**

I have deleted the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute from the files by running

```bash
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine *.pdf
```

as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/28384/what-should-i-do-about-com-apple-quarantine). So far, I have not come across a PDF that won't open in Preview using `open -a Preview.app ...`. If the problem appears not to persist, I will happily accept an answer from @David Anderson if they wish to post one, or I will write one myself to this effect.

Comment: What does `ls -lOe@ my file.pdf` show? This will include file flags (`-O`), Access Control Lists (`-e`) and extended attributes (`-@`).

Comment: Is this specific to Terminal and `open`? What happens when you use Finder and open it in Preview from there?

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, try resetting the permissions on the file: `chmod 644 myfile.pdf` and the owner `chown bashfuloctopus:staff myfile.pdf` then try opening it again.

Comment: I have added the information above, as an edit to my question. In essence: there is more confusing behaviour and the problem is not resolved by resetting permissions + ownerships. @David please let me know if you spot anything from the flags, ACLs and extended attributes; I am unaccustomed to looking at these items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view file flags, access control lists (ACLs) and extended attributes for all the `.pdf` files in the current working directory by entering the command below.

```
ls -lOe@ *.pdf
```

> Note: The option `-O` is for file flags, `-e` is for Access Control Lists and `-@` is for extended attributes.

As the OP already stated, the `com.apple.quarantine` extended attribute was causing the problem. The OP removed this extended attribute by entering the command below.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine *.pdf
```

---

### FYI

The command below can be used to remove most existing file flags.

```
chflags noopaque,dump,nouappnd,nouchg,nohidden *.pdf
```

> Note: Using `dump` instead of `nodump` is not a mistake.

Or, the following more comprehensive command *may* be used.

```
sudo chflags 0 *.pdf
```

The command below can be used to remove most existing access control lists (ACLs).

```
chmod -N *.pdf
```

Finally, the command below can be used to remove most existing extended attributes.

```
xattr -c *.pdf
```